# Java_org_cocos2dx_lib_Cocos2dxRenderer_nativeOnPause

Tags: android, crash, cocos2d-x, segmentation-fault

In Google Play I have daily crash reporting ever-increasing.

```
signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR)
Java_org_cocos2dx_lib_Cocos2dxRenderer_nativeOnPause
```

backtrace:

```
pid: 0, tid: 0 >>> com.Feelinglucky.swipelight <<<

backtrace:
  #00  pc 00000000002ca46c  /data/app/com.Feelinglucky.swipelight-2/lib/arm/libplayer.so (Java_org_cocos2dx_lib_Cocos2dxRenderer_nativeOnPause+7)
  #01  pc 0000000001c0c02d  /data/app/com.Feelinglucky.swipelight-2/oat/arm/base.odex
```

How can  i solve this problem? Thanks in advance

Comment: Are there any others logs? Looks like you going to background and your app fails. Try to debug going background/foreground.

Comment: There are no other logs, this is all I know. I can not even recreate the bug because it never happened to me. I tried to debug and go in the background but no strange logs or strange crashes.

Comment: Well one is for sure that it happens at `nativeOnPause`, in most cases means your main activity goes to background. Maybe you call another activities like facebook_auth activity or advertising activities. Look up in other libraries which calls activities. Good Luck!